# Calculating Overdraft Using Validator

Tags: php, oop

I am attempting to learn PHP OOP by converting some exercises from a couple of Java classes into it.  Subtle differences aside, I have been relatively successful until this conversion.  The idea was that you would have a bank account and balance to start.  Using a series of transaction types, either withdrawal or deposit, you would output the balance after the transaction.  If the withdrawal amount was greater than the balance it would still process the transaction and output the new balance with an added $30 overdraft fee added to it.  Seemed simple enough.

However, no matter what I try it will not validate the withdrawal using the validateWithdrawalAmount to return a '0' or 'FALSE" if funds are not available.  I have searched online all over and have not been able to find a solution.  This code is from my most recent attempt at using integers rather than TRUE/FALSE, which I've tried case-sensitive/-insensitive.  I suspect this issue is related to some oddity in how PHP processes boolean but I am confounded.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please keep in mind these are aimed at learning, not beauty.  However, if you see something that could improve my code, outside of the solution, feel free to let me know.  I am always looking for constructive criticism.  I added comments to help with understanding.

**class_bank_account.php**

```
<?php
class BankAccount
{
    // constant(s)
    const OVERDRAFT_CHARGE = 30;

    // variable(s)
    private $accountNumber;
    private $balance;

    /**
     * Construct the object with set parameters.
     * 
     * @param   String  $sAccountNumber     Account number to use.
     * @param   Double  $dBalance           Starting balance.
     **/
    public function __construct($sAccountNumber, $dBalance)
    {
        $this->accountNumber = $sAccountNumber;
        $this->balance = $dBalance;
    }

    /**
     * Process a withdrawal by, first, checking to see if there are
     * sufficient funds and then subtract the amount of the transaction
     * from the balance.  If the balance is less than the transaction
     * amount then add the overdraft fee.
     *
     * @param   Double $dWithdrawal         Withdrawal amount.
     **/
    public function processWithdrawal($dWithdrawal)
    {
        // check if the withdrawal amount is in good standing with internal function
        $goodStanding = $this->validateWithdrawalAmount($dWithdrawal);

        // process withdrawal
        if($goodStanding == 0)
        {
            $this->balance += $dWithdrawal - self::OVERDRAFT_CHARGE;
        }
        elseif($goodStanding == 1)
        {
            $this->balance += $dWithdrawal;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error"; // this was added as a way to confirm flow
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validates the withdrawal amount to confirm if there are
     * sufficient funds or not.
     *
     * @param   Double  $dWithdrawal        Withdrawal Amount
     * @return  Boolean                         True or False
     **/
    public function validateWithdrawalAmount($dWithdrawal)
    {
        $sufficientFunds = 1;

        if($dWithdrawal > $this->balance)
        {
            $sufficientFunds = 0;
        }

        return $sufficientFunds; // return either 1 or 0 for True or False
    }

    /**
     * Processes deposits into the account.
     *
     * @param   Double  $dDeposit       Deposit amount.
     **/
    public function processDeposit($dDeposit)
    {
        $this->balance += $dDeposit;
    }

    /**
     * Get the account number.
     *
     * @return String   Account number.
     **/
    public function get_AccountNumber()
    {
        return $this->accountNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set the account number.
     *
     * @param  String   $sAccountNumber     Account number to use.
     **/
    public function set_AccountNumber($sAccountNumber)
    {
        $this->accountNumber = $sAccountNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Get the account balance.
     *
     * @return  Double  Account balance.
     **/
    public function get_Balance()
    {
        return $this->balance;
    }
}
?>
```

**bankdriver.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bank Driver</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        // our class
        include "class_bank_account.php";

        // array of transactions
        $trans = array(
            -20.00,
            120.00,
            -35.00,
            -251.00,
            -2000.00,
            3000.00,
            -4.00,
            -60.00,
            -555.00
        );

        // length of array for counting foreach loop
        $array_length = count($trans);

        // create our bank account object
        $account = new BankAccount("BJS15923", 2000);
    ?>
    <h1><?php echo $account->get_AccountNumber(); ?></h1>
    <table border="1px" width="50%">
        <tr><th>AMOUNT</th><th>BALANCE</th></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><?php echo $account->get_Balance(); ?></td></tr>

        <?php
            // cycle through the array
            foreach($trans as $amount)
            {
                // output the amount of the transaction
                echo '<tr><td>'.$amount.'</td><td>';
                if($amount < 0)
                {
                    // processess withdrawal if transaction was negative
                    $account->processWithdrawal($amount);
                }
                elseif($amount > 0)
                {
                    // process deposit if transaction was positive
                    $account->processDeposit($amount);
                }

                // output our new balance
                echo $account->get_Balance().'</td></tr>';
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your `self::` should be `$this->`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.  The issue is that within the 'validateWithdrawalAmount' function it never enters the if statement like it never thinks the balance is less than the withdrawal amount passed into it.  I can test this by adding an echo of the '$goodstanding' variable in the 'processWithdrawal' function.

Comment: think i worked this out - withdrawal is a negative, so the negative is not going to be larger than the balance, you need to to compare the withdraw as an absolute value (abs) not the negative. the oop is file, its a logic issue

Comment: Dagon, you rock!  Throw this in an answer so I can mark it as the answer, please.  I cannot believe I missed something so simple.  Guess this is what comes about when you stare at something too long and try to completely rewrite it multiple times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you're saying "if a negative number" (for a withdrawal) is greater than my balance, then..." - see the example where:

1. Your balance sits at $1814
2. You want to withdraw $2000 (-$2000 transaction)
3. Your function says `if (-2000 > 1814) { ... }` - this is where it's returning true instead of false. It should be `if (2000 > 1814) { ... }` where it's comparing the amount you want to withdraw ($2000) against your balance ($1814).

You can fix this by adding an [`abs()`](http://php.net/abs) call to force the number to be positive:

```
$sufficientFunds = true;

if (abs($dWithdrawal) > $this->getBalance()) {
    $sufficientFunds = false;
}
return (bool) $sufficientFunds;
```

[See a working example here](https://eval.in/388880). I've only changed a couple of other things in your code - using booleans instead of 1 and 0, some PHPDoc changes (double isn't a PHP type, float is), returning an instance of the class from setters is normally a good idea (`return $this` - to allow for method chaining), removed underscores from method names, prefix protected and private class properties with underscores, etc. Mostly just stylistic things.

Comment: Scrowler, Dagon beat you to that solution but didn't put it in an answer.  Your answer was more thorough, however.  I really appreciate the information about OOP, also.  I wish I could mark both of you right!

Comment: i was typing up my answer -oh well :(